# Making smaller distribution points

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

Is there a way to make points from the Distribute Points on Faces node smaller, to look like actual points?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, put a *Set Point Radius* node after the *Distribute Points on Faces* node:

[image: set point radius]